# Socket io server is confusing clients on emit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Im trying to develop a todo app with socket io where TODOs are filtered by user logged in, everything works fine except when i refresh both sessions (user A and User B), Socket IO server emits the B's info to user A. I don't know if is it a socket io server or client issue.

When each user logs in, in different moment, the data is showed at front end perfectly, but when they refresh the page at same time is when the issue occurs.

I already tried to map the userid with the socket.id and in server side I emit to the specific socketid, searching it with userid key. Console logs prints and seems to be all ok but the issue keeps in the front end.

**Socket IO Server side**

```
 mapSessions[userid] = socket.id;
        
 console.log(30,userid,mapSessions);
 console.log(31,userid,mapSessions[userid]);

      
 //EMIT ALL USER TICKETS 
 this.io.to(mapSessions[userid]).emit('ticketList', await getTickets(userid));
```

**Socket IO Client side**

```
  const connectSocket = useCallback(() => {
    
    if (token) {
       
        const socketTemp = io.connect(serverPath, {
            transports: ['websocket'],
            autoConnect: true,
            reconnection:true,
            forceNew: true,
            query: {
                'x-token': token
            }
        });
        dispatch(setSocket(socketTemp));
    }
}, [token, serverPath, dispatch]);
```

The token that Im sending within query from client side is used in server side to get the userid and session status.

**NOTE**: Seems like the server emits to the last id received. I mean: If user A and user B refresh the page and user A is the last one on send the request to socket server, the server sends A's info to user B too. :/

Socket.io : 3.03

Comment: are you updating ```mapSessions[userid] = socket.id;``` whenever socket connects?

Comment: @SanskarBansal yes, the map is updated on every connection (on every page refresh when new socket session is created)

Comment: are you sure about this function ```getTickets(userid)``` ? that this always returns correct values ?

Comment: Yes, this function do the query to db filtering in the query with the userid sent. I also print the token and the userid within getTickets function and are the same that i printed below socket connection. Everything seems to work ok if the users don't refresh at same time

Comment: Have you tried to join a room with each user on the server side? In one of the apps I made I used this approach. `const token = socket.handshake.query.x-token; socket.join(token);` and then when you send down the info use `io.in(token).emit('ticketList', await getTickets(userid));` assuming that each user is alone in his own room. In my case this was done with userId so even if refreshed the user will always end up in a room alone with his userId as an identifier which is unique.